# Spring - Annotation - Controller - Use setRedirectAction in controller class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

My problem is that when I am trying to redirect my users to another URL in the @ActionMapping phase spring tries to set the render parameters after the redirect. This causes the following error to always appear in my logs:

"Cannot set renderparameter after sendredirect"

I have found that in previous, deprecated versions of the controller classes you had the possibility to use "setRedirectAction" to a boolean value to be able to decide if you should set the render parameter or not.

I am now wondering how you can set this parameter in an annotade controller to be able to get rid of the problem above.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue. The problem was that we where redirecting to another URL outside the Scope of the portlet. But before that was done spring was trying to handle the org.springframework.ui.ModelMap and then it tryed to modify renderparameters.

I cleared the modelMap using the "clear" method and then spring had no modelmap to handle so therefore the error message dissappeared.